# Loading gif image in background?

Tags: xcode, swift, asynchronous, gif

**Description/ What I've tried**

I imported a library that lets me beautifully load images asynchronously into my UITableView (https://github.com/natelyman/SwiftImageLoader) . The problem is that it doesn't support gifs. So I did case statement to independently retrieve the gif if need be and display the gif using another library.

**Problem**

Now the problem is that whenever I try loading a gif, the scrolling gets really choppy.

**Question**

Can someone please help me figure this out? Does it involve putting it on a background thread? If so, how?

**Code**

```
if let url = NSURL(string: arrayByVotes[indexPath.row].objectForKey("thumbnail") as NSString) {

        let imageURL = arrayByVotes[indexPath.row].objectForKey("thumbnail") as NSString

        if (imageURL.lowercaseString.rangeOfString("gif") != nil) {

                    cell.thumbnail.image = UIImage.animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFURL(url)


        } else {

            ImageLoader.sharedLoader.imageForUrl(arrayByVotes[indexPath.row].objectForKey("thumbnail") as NSString, completionHandler:{(image: UIImage?, url: String) in

                cell.thumbnail.image = image
            })

        }

    }
```

Comment: Why are you dispatching from the main queue to the main queue?

Comment: That was just something I tried :). It didn't work. I'm going to edit it and take it out of the question. My bad

Answer (score -1):

Maybe having many gif images in memory at the same time is affecting the performance of the scrolling. Try removing the images from the cells that are invisible and add the image only when the cell will show up. A good method for this would be tableView(_:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:) from the UITableViewDelegate